# Why is there an ambiguous method call between long, float and decimal methods when using a long as a paramater?

Tags: c#, npgsql, c#-8.0

I am trying to build a `NpgsqlSimpleTypeHandler<ulong>` to handle converting `ulong` values to `long` values so they can be stored in my PostgreSQL database, and vise-versa.

When I try and call Npgsql's `Int64handler.ValidtaeAndGetLength` after converting a `ulong` to a `long` with `Convert.ToInt64(value)`, attempting to pass the newly converted `long` gives me an ambiguous method call error.

```
private readonly Int64Handler handler;
...
public override int ValidateAndGetLength(ulong value, NpgsqlParameter? parameter)
{
    long val = Convert.ToInt64(value);
    return handler.ValidateAndGetLength(val, parameter);
}
```

Error Message:

```
Error   CS0121
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'Int64Handler.ValidateAndGetLength(float, NpgsqlParameter?)' and
'Int64Handler.ValidateAndGetLength(decimal, NpgsqlParameter?)'
```

Why, when even with `Int64Handler.ValidateAndGetLength(long, NpgsqlParameter?)` exsisting, do I wind up with the ambiguous method call error?

[*Npgsql Int64Handler documentation*](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.TypeHandlers.NumericHandlers.Int64Handler.html)

*[7/21/2020 14:23 EST] Updated tags to include C#-8.0*

Comment: Have you tried using float instead of long? e.g. ... `float val = Convert.ToInt64(value);`

Comment: Using a float will compile properly, but will using a float have an adverse effect while I am dealing with long values that are Snowflakes (Discord IDs)?

Comment: On an unrelated note, it's somewhat discouraged to write your own type handlers. Although those APIs are public, they're meant more for "official" (read: maintained) Npgsql plugins, and may break at any point (some improvements are planned for Npgsql 5.0 which may do that). Just be aware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between `ValidateAndGetLength(long, NpgsqlParameter?)` and other overloads in the `Int64Handler` class is that the first method is actually overriding the method in the class `NpgsqlSimpleTypeHandler<long>` that implements `INpgsqlSimpleTypeHandler<long>`, and other methods are implementing the methods in the `INpgsqlSimpleTypeHandler<T>` interface directly.

From [C# 6 draft language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#overload-resolution):

> For example, the set of candidates for a method invocation does not include methods marked override (Member lookup), and methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable (Method invocations).

The "Member lookup" section expands on this further:

> First, a set of accessible members named N is determined:
>
> If T is a type parameter, then the set is the union of the sets of accessible members named N in each of the types specified as a primary constraint or secondary constraint (Type parameter constraints) for T, along with the set of accessible members named N in object.
>
> Otherwise, the set consists of all accessible (Member access) members named N in T, including inherited members and the accessible members named N in object. If T is a constructed type, the set of members is obtained by substituting type arguments as described in Members of constructed types. **Members that include an override modifier are excluded from the set.**

I managed to reproduce the issue with the sample code:

```
using System;

interface IA<T>
{
    int X(T x);
}

abstract class A<T> : IA<T>
{
    public abstract int X(T x);
}

class B : A<long>, IA<float>, IA<decimal>
{
    public override int X(long x)
    {
        return 8;
    }
    
    public int X(float x)
    {
        return 8;
    }
    
    public int X(decimal x)
    {
        return 8;
    }
}
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var b = new B();
        var a = (A<long>)b;
        Console.WriteLine(a.X(42L));
        // Console.WriteLine(b.X(42L)); // broken
    }
}
```

You can use the workaround of casting the handler to `NpgsqlSimpleTypeHandler<long>` and calling that method instead.

Comment: Thank fixed the compilation error, thanks! My code is still broken, but for completely different reasons now!

Comment: @devNull I was actually digging into the C# 6 draft language specification, but you were quicker, so I'm going to include the quote in my answer.

Comment: @milleniumbug I probably should have mentioned it in my question, but if you are going to include quotes from the language specification I would look at the C# 8.0 specs, as I am using C# 8.0

Comment: @AndrewBounds Ah, so far it seems we only have the C# 6 draft spec, the newer ones seem to be proposals that describe the differences from the C# 6 one. I had assumed this aspect didn't change between versions.

Comment: @milleniumbug seeing as it worked on my end, no I don't think it has changed. Just thought that if there was a C# 8 spec it should be used, but I didn't actually look for anything myself, so I evidently didn't find the lack of a specification.

Answer (score -2):

Some of the implicit type conversion rules in C# are borrowed from those of Java, which allow implicit conversion from float to double, but not vice versa, and which allow implicit conversions from any integer type to float or double, but not vice versa.  This has the rather curious effect of causing conversions from integer types to `float` to be regarded as unambiguously preferable to conversions to `double`, despite the greater loss of precision.  This wouldn't be a problem when calling overloads of a function which accepts overloads of all integer types, but can be a bit quirky when passing an integer value to a function that accepts both `float` and `double`.

C# adds another wrinkle to Java's type rules, however, with its `decimal` type.  All integer types may be implicitly converted to `decimal`, but `decimal` cannot implicitly be converted to or from any other floating-point type.  Thus, `decimal` isn't preferable to `float`, and nor is `float` preferable to `decimal`.  If an attempt is made to pass a `long` to a function which would accept `float`, `double`, and `decimal`, but isn't prepared to accept `long`, a compiler would have no basis for regarding either `float` or `decimal` as being preferable to the other.  Ironically, in most such cases the best type would be `double`, and there are relatively few cases where the `decimal` type would be appropriate, but its existence helps alert the programmer to the need to explicitly convert to `double`, rather than having the compiler silently convert the `long` to `float`.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question that was asked. _"If an attempt is made to pass a long to a function which would accept float, double, and decimal, but isn't prepared to accept long"_ -- the OP has specifically stated that there _is_ in fact an overload that accepts `long` as the parameter type. Why wouldn't the compiler choose the exactly-matching overload instead of complaining about ambiguity between two overloads that require a conversion?

Comment: This makes sense, but why does the compiler fail to pick the overload of the method that does accept a long value, instead throwing an error?

Comment: @PeterDuniho: It's not listing such an overload as existing.  I don't see the rest of the code, but it's worth noting that generic types are never considered as overloads for anything other than the same generic types, or other generic types that are constrained to them.

Comment: @supercat I linked the Int64Handler documentation for this reason. There is a version of the method that accepts a long value, even if it does not appear in the error message: ```public override int ValidateAndGetLength(long value, NpgsqlParameter parameter)```

Comment: @AndrewBounds: Is the type of the second argument  `NpgsqlParameter` or a nullable `NpgsqlParameter?`?

Comment: @supercat Visual Studio says the second parameter is a nullable ```NpgsqlParameter?```. Which matches the argument provided. (If this didnt answer what you are asking could you clarify your question?)

Comment: _"It's not listing such an overload as existing"_ -- huh? See https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.TypeHandlers.NumericHandlers.Int64Handler.html#Npgsql_TypeHandlers_NumericHandlers_Int64Handler_ValidateAndGetLength_System_Int64_Npgsql_NpgsqlParameter_. There is the subtle difference of the nullable second parameter, but that should not prevent a non-nullable reference from matching during overload resolution.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: In the sample code to reproduce the issue above, although the override of X has its argument type declared as `long`, the argument type of the original method being overridden is of generic type parameter `T`, and overload resolution tends not to consider generic types even in cases where a type might be known.